# TWTweetComposeViewController a strange indentation on top

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

When you call the following `twitter` method I always get a strange indentation on top.

[image]

**Here is my method:**

```
- (void)twitter {
    if ([TWRequest class]) {
        TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [twitter setInitialText:titleDetail];
        [twitter addImage:imgPreview];
        [twitter addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkPost]];
        [self presentViewController:twitter animated:YES completion:nil];
        twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult res) {
            if (res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Выполнено" message:@"Ваш твит успешно опубликован" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];       
            } else if (res == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ошибка" message:@"Ваш твит неопубликован" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show]; 
            }    
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        };  
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

---

## **Update: FIXED**

The problem was this:
When the application loads (which displays a splash screen) I hide the status bar.

> The status bar is initially hidden.

And then, in **`AppDelegate.m`**:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
```

The problem was precisely in `20`:

```
CGRectMake (0, 20, 320, 460);
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question; in fact, please do so, rather than leaving this question appear unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this: When load application (which displays splash screen) I hid status bar.

```
Status bar is initially hidden YES
```

And then, in AppDelegate.m:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: NO withAnimation: NO];
[UIApplication sharedApplication]. KeyWindow.frame = CGRectMake (0, 20, 320, 460);
```

The problem was precisely in 20:

```
CGRectMake (0, 20, 320, 460);
```